# WooCommerce WC()->session->get is not getting recognized

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies, woocommerce

We have created a site where a user enters a coupon code and it logs them in by creating a cookie by the name of `couponid`, then we save that cookie to the WooCommerce session because that cookie actually is the category id from which the products are displayed.

Now sometimes the products get displayed, sometimes not, and whenever our custom cookie is set in the browser and we go to `/wp-admin` to login, it gives us the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

The above error on the login screen of WordPress is coming from the following function in our `functions.php` file:

```
function gfc_insert_coupon_code_to_session(){

if( 
    is_user_logged_in() 
    || ! array_key_exists( 'couponid', $_COOKIE ) 
    || WC()->session->get( 'couponid', 0 )
){
    return;
}

$couponID = esc_attr( $_COOKIE['couponid'] );

    if( $couponID ){
        WC()->session->set( 'couponid', $couponID );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'gfc_insert_coupon_code_to_session' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
WC()->session->set( 'couponid', $couponID );
```

Before calling:

```
WC()->session->get( 'couponid', 0 )
```

Comment: Tried, didn't work. The problem is that it is not recognizing the session as an object, so it gives error on both set() and get() as member function of an non-object.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer to the question - but I was just looking for how to do a WC() session get and set and your answer told me that - hence my up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Test if your are on Back Office, `WC()->session` isn't set:

```
if( !is_admin() ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if( !is_admin() ) { ... }` fix

did the job for me. I changed the email template and if I tried to resend the email from the backend I received this error. So the admin fix was good.