# WC_Customer() class not working

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

When I am logged in as a user on my woocommerce website and I try to create a new `WC_Customer`, I get a fatal error telling me:

> "Call to a member function get() on null"

I have tried to do this with a plugin as well as in the functions.php file of my theme, with the same result.

This is the line provoking the error, in the WC_Customer class:

```
$this->_data = (array) WC()->session->get( 'customer' );
```

**Note:** The website is still running locally

Comment: Are you seeing the error in the Admin dashboard only?

Comment: No, I get a full page of PHP error

Comment: Sorry, I worked on other stuff and forgot to check this post. Your solution did work for me, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix with `if( !is_admin() )` before, to test if your are on Back Office, because `WC()->session` isn't set:

```
if( !is_admin() ) { 
    $this_data = WC()->session->get( 'customer' );
    this->_data = $this_data;
}
```

Have you set before some data in it *(you get this message because there is no data in it)*:

```
if( !is_admin() ){
    $some_data = 'some_data';
    WC()->session->set( 'customer' , $some_data );
}
```

Related threads:

- [how to use session in woocommerce pages like we use normal php session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199656/how-to-use-session-in-woocommerce-pages-like-we-use-normal-php-session/27200794#27200794)
- [WooCommerce WC()->session->get is not getting recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031171/woocommerce-wc-session-get-is-not-getting-recognized/32800882#32800882)